# Try to find conditions to prove the Mandarin's lemma (basic case).

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, modular-arithmetic, congruences, chinese-remainder-theorem

We know that according to the CRT if we have  $m,n\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $\gcd(m,n)=1$ then the system

\begin{cases}
  x\equiv a \pmod m \\
  x \equiv b \pmod n
\end{cases}

has an unique $x \pmod{mn}$ for solution.

> I try to copy the proof of that statement to prove that if we have
>   $m,n\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $1\ne d=\gcd(m,n)$ then the system
>
> \begin{cases}   x\equiv a \pmod m \\   x \equiv b \pmod n \end{cases}
>   has (an unique ?) solution $x \pmod{lcm(m,n)}$.

Here is my attempt :

By Bachet-Bézout's identity we can claim that there exists $u,v\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $um+vn=d$.

Multiplying this equation by $x$ : $uxm+vxn=dx$ and using the fact that $x=km+a=ln+b,\ l,k\in \mathbb{Z}$ we obtain : $ubm+van\equiv dx \pmod{lcm(m,n)}$

But we want to build $x$ and the problem is that $d$ in not invertible in $(\mathbb{Z}/lcm(m,n)\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ (by definition).

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Anyway the system does not *always* have a solution: it has one if and only if $a\equiv b\mod\gcd(m,n)$.

Comment: **Hint** $\ \exists x,j,k\!:\ a+jm = x = b+kn\iff \exists j,k\!:\ kn-jm = a-b\overset{\rm Bezout}\iff (m,n)\mid a-b$

Comment: Uniqueness is only implied with $m,n$ relatively prime.  $d$ is the greatest common denominator, $(m,n)$, and while $d$ does not have to be invertible, invertibility does imply the existence of a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some details on how it goes: as said in comments, there can be a solution only if $a\equiv b \pmod{ d=\gcd(m,n)}$.

So suppose this condition is satisfied, and set $m'=\dfrac md$, $n'=\dfrac nd$, $b=a+rd\;$ and $X=\dfrac{x-a}d$. The system of congruences can be rewritten as
$$\begin{cases}x-a\equiv 0&\!\!\pmod{m'd}\\
x-a\equiv rd&\!\!\pmod{n'd}\end{cases} \iff\begin{cases}X\equiv 0&\!\!\pmod{m'}\\
X\equiv r&\!\!\pmod{n'}\end{cases} $$
As $m',n'$ are coprime, this system has a unique solution modulo $m'n'$, obtained from a *Bézout's relation* between $m$ and $n$: $um+vn=d$:
$$X\equiv rum'+0vn' \pmod{m'n'}\quad\text{whence}\quad x\equiv a+rum \pmod{dm'n'=\operatorname{lcm}(m,n)}. $$

Comment: Really nice thank you. The key was the "coprime" factors. But how do we find this condition of $a\equiv b \pmod d$ ?

Comment: Correct is `\pmod` not `\bmod` (the latter abuse can be quite confusing for beginners)

Comment: @Bill Dubuque: I  used `\bmod` for spacing reasons, not in the usual sense of \bmod, so it shouldn't be confusional, I think.

Comment: What's wrong if we do not suppose that $a\equiv b \pmod d$ ?

Comment: Well, there's no solution, since the existence of solutions *implies* $a$ and $b$ are congruent mod. $\gcd(m,n)$.

Comment: @bernard Unfortunately it does confuse many students and it also misleads students into believing that such errant notation is correct.